# get last typed and changed input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with this.

I have 3 inputs, one `type=range` and the other two `type=text`.

I have managed that the three inputs are related. That is, if i change one input, the other inputs change too. In this part, the code works fine

My problem is that i want to return a variable that equals to 0 or 1 deppending of the element changed.

Let me explain, if the user move the cursor of the type range, or type in the first input,  `elmChanged` return 1. But, in the other case, if the user type in the second input, `elmChanged` return 0

I have tried using `onchange`, and `onkeyup`, but, i couldn't find a solution, because, if i change the value of one input, the other two inputs change too.
I have tried using also `onkeyup`, but i neither couldn't find a solution because i couldn't manage how to change the value of `elmChanged`.

My question is how can i do this and where to load `elmChanged` depending of the last element changed.

```js
var elmChanged = ""

    function RangeChanged(){
        amountInput.value=amountRange.value; 
        amountInput_2.value=amountRange.value * 2
        // how can i do that
        elmChanged = 1
    }

    function FirstInputChanged(){
        amountRange.value=amountInput.value; 
        amountInput_2.value=amountInput.value * 2;
        // how can i do that
        elmChanged = 1
    }

    function SecondInputChanged(){
        amountRange.value=amountInput_2.value; 
        amountInput.value=amountInput_2.value / 2;
        // how can i do that
        elmChanged = 0
    }

console.log(elmChanged)
ElementInputChanged.value = elmChanged
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="range" name="amountRange" id="amountRange" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1" oninput="RangeChanged()"  />
  <input type="text" name="amountInput" id="amountInput" min="0" max="100" value="50" oninput="FirstInputChanged()"  />
  <input type="text" name="amountInput_2" id="amountInput_2" min="0" max="200" value="100" oninput="SecondInputChanged()" />
        
  <span>Element Changed:</span> <span id="ElementInputChanged"></span>

</form>
```

Comment: There's an error in the code snippet -- can you make sure that `secondChanged` is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it to a function.
By the way: `span` doesn't have `value` like inputs. I changed it to `textContent`.

Snippet:

```js
/*var elmChanged = ""*/

function RangeChanged(){
  amountInput.value=amountRange.value; 
  amountInput_2.value=amountRange.value * 2
  // how can i do that
  elmChanged(1);
}

function FirstInputChanged(){
  amountRange.value=amountInput.value; 
  amountInput_2.value=amountInput.value * 2;
  // how can i do that
  elmChanged(1);
}

function SecondInputChanged(){
  amountRange.value=amountInput_2.value; 
  amountInput.value=amountInput_2.value / 2;
  // how can i do that
  elmChanged(0);
}
function elmChanged(num) {
  console.log(num)
  ElementInputChanged.textContent = num
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="range" name="amountRange" id="amountRange" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1" oninput="RangeChanged()"  />
  <input type="text" name="amountInput" id="amountInput" min="0" max="100" value="50" oninput="FirstInputChanged()"  />
  <input type="text" name="amountInput_2" id="amountInput_2" min="0" max="200" value="100" oninput="SecondInputChanged()" />
        
  <span>Element Changed:</span> <span id="ElementInputChanged"></span>

</form>
```